# How to use multiple controls to display each character in a string in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm using this code:

```
List<TextBlock> BackTextBlocks = new List<TextBlock>();
List<String> AStringList = new List<String>();
...
for (int i = 0; i < TotalCount; i++){
    BackTextBlocks.Add(new TextBlock());
    BackTextBlocks[i].Text = AStringList[i];
    BackTextBlocks[i].Measure(new Size(Double.PositiveInfinity, Double.PositiveInfinity));
    BackTextBlocks[i].Arrange(new Rect(BackTextBlocks[i].DesiredSize));
    BackTextBlocks[i].Margin = new Thickness(i * BackTextBlocks[i].ActualWidth, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

It is normal to display Chinese and Japanese characters like this:[image]

but once English or other symbols are displayed, all the characters will be stacked together like this:[image]

The full effect should look like this:
[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you please add your code here, so we can see what have you tried?

Comment: Oh, thank you for your comment. I used a Canvas and put my TextBlock on it, using margin to display the hole string. Just like this `BackTextBlocks[i].Margin = new Thickness(i * BackTextBlocks[i].ActualWidth, 0, 0, 0);`

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @BionicCode I am sorry about that, I will try to improve my questioning skills.

Comment: Please don't post snippets without any context. Those snippets only have a meaning to to you , because you know their actual context. This includes to show how you are using the BackTextBlocks collection to display the text. If you have GUI issues you must show both,  the UI related code and the data related code. Otherwise we can't review your code to identify issues. However, don't create TextBlcoks explicitely, but use a DataTemplate. You are also not supposed to call Measure and Arrange at this stage as it will be called by the framework when it will render the elements.

Comment: Also your question is not clear. Can you elaborate more on what you are trying to do and what kind of problems you are experiencing, please?

Comment: @BionicCode Thanks for your answer! I want to use multiple controls to display each character in a string individually. I updated my question, the normal display should be similar to Picture 1, the abnormal display should be similar to Picture 2.

Comment: What you are trying to doe here is not the most efficient way to display text. Why do you need to create a TextBlock for each character?

Comment: @BionicCode I have updated my question. I need to display some smaller characters on top of certain characters (something like comments), so I use a TextBlock to display each character.

Comment: Is this meant to be used for a few brief sentences or on a text of random size?

Comment: @BionicCode Yes. The length of the text is not fixed, it is usually short sentences (all text is lyrics).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not manually create `TextBlock` elements. Better focus on the data and let the framework create the `TextBlock` elements for you by defining a corresponding `DataTemplate` ([Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/data-templating-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)).

Also you should not call `Measure` an `Arrange` explicitly. The framework will do it for the moment you render them. It's absolutely not necessary in your case. Simply layout an element by setting its properties like `Margin`, `Padding`, `HorizontalAlignment` or `VerticalAlignment`. Use a `Panel` for more complex layouts. Calculating the elements size manually made your code overly complicated and therefore only creates another error source (which you actually exhibit).

You need a more sophisticated abstraction of your document, which contains of lines. In your case you must also abstract each character as you want to annotate them individually.

The following example uses two nested `ItemsControl` elements to display the document: the outer `ItemsControl` displays the lines (vertically). The second `ItemsControl` is nested into the first to display a set of annotated characters.

To abstract a annotated character, the example introduces a data type `AnnotatedCharacter`. The type `AnnotatedCharacterLine` simply consolidates a set of `AnnotatedCharacter` items to form a line:

**AnnotatedCharacter.cs**

```cs
public struct AnnotatedCharacter
{
  public AnnotatedCharacter(char character, string annotation)
  {
    this.Character = character;
    this.Annotation = annotation;
  }

  public char Character { get; }
  public string Annotation { get; }
}
```

**AnnotatedCharacterLine.cs**

```cs
public struct AnnotatedCharacterLine
{
  public AnnotatedCharacterLine(IList<AnnotatedCharacter> annotatedCharacters)
  {
    this.AnnotatedCharacters = annotatedCharacters;
  }

  public static AnnotatedCharacterLine BlankLine 
    => new AnnotatedCharacterLine(new List<AnnotatedCharacter>() { new AnnotatedCharacter(' ', string.Empty) });

  public IList<AnnotatedCharacter> AnnotatedCharacters { get; }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  public IList<AnnotatedCharacterLine> AnnotatedCharacterLines
  {
    get => (IList<AnnotatedCharacterLine>)GetValue(AnnotatedCharacterLinesProperty);
    set => SetValue(AnnotatedCharacterLinesProperty, value);
  }

  public static readonly DependencyProperty AnnotatedCharacterLinesProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "AnnotatedCharacterLines", 
    typeof(IList<AnnotatedCharacterLine>), 
    typeof(MainWindow), 
    new PropertyMetadata(default));

  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();

    this.AnnotatedCharacterLines = new ObservableCollection<AnnotatedCharacterLine>();
    this.Loaded += OnLoadedAsync;
  }  
    
  private async void OnLoadedAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
    => await CreateMultilineTextAsync();

  public async Task CreateMultilineTextAsync()
  {
    StringBuilder multilineTextBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    multilineTextBuilder.AppendLine("The world is gonna be a better place");
    multilineTextBuilder.AppendLine("if we spread a little love.");

    string multilineText = multilineTextBuilder.ToString();

    using var stringReader = new StringReader(multilineText);

    var annotationCharacterGenerator = new Random();
    string? line = string.Empty;
    while ((line = await stringReader.ReadLineAsync()) is not null)
    {
      // Add a blank line if line only contains only a line break
      if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
      {
        this.AnnotatedCharacterLines.Add(AnnotatedCharacterLine.BlankLine);
        continue;
      }

      var annotatedCharacters = new ObservableCollection<AnnotatedCharacter>();
       
      // Create a collection of char from a string
      foreach (char character in line)
      {
        // A random two character annotation or blank if character is a white space
        string annotation = char.IsWhiteSpace(character)
          ? string.Empty
          : $"{(char)annotationCharacterGenerator.Next(97, 123)}{(char)annotationCharacterGenerator.Next(97, 123)}";

        var annotatedCharacter = new AnnotatedCharacter(character, annotation);
        annotatedCharacters.Add(annotatedCharacter);
      }

      var annotatedCharacterLine = new AnnotatedCharacterLine(annotatedCharacters);
      this.AnnotatedCharacterLines.Add(annotatedCharacterLine);
    }
  }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window>

  <!-- An ItemsControl to display a collection lines to make a text -->
  <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}, Path=AnnotatedCharacterLines}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <VirtualizingStackPanel />
      </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    <ItemsControl.Template>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="ItemsControl">
        <ScrollViewer CanContentScroll="True">
          <ItemsPresenter />
        </ScrollViewer>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Template>

    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:AnnotatedCharacterLine}">

       <!-- A nested ItemsControl to display a collection of characters that make a line -->
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding AnnotatedCharacters}">
          <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
              <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
          </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
          <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:AnnotatedCharacter}">
              <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Annotation}"
                            FontSize="10"
                            VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Character}"
                            FontSize="42" />
              </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
          </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
  </ItemsControl>
</Window>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  I will continue to improve my questioning skills.

Comment: I'm happy if I was able to help you. Don't worry.

Comment: The example requires you to use C#9. I hope you can convert the few related lines in case you are running the old .NET Framework instead of .NET 5+. Let me know if you need help.

Comment: Hello. I am using your code and he is behaving very well. I'm actually making a lyrics player, using two layers of ItemsControl, which I put in a Canvas (to get the width of the currently displayed text on the page). The layer below is fully revealed at the beginning. The layer above has an initial width of 0 and will increase its width over time, I used a DispatcherTimer to update its width, but it seems the update is very slow. Is there any way to solve this problem.