# UI performance issue when I try to change the width of the ItemsControl in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm making a dynamic lyrics player using the `ItemsControl` from the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72629354/how-to-use-multiple-controls-to-display-each-character-in-a-string-in-wpf).

I use two `ItemsControls` that are stacked on top of each other and both are placed in different `Canvas` (to get the actual width of the text currently being displayed), `Canvas` are placed in the `Grid` to ensure that the `Canvas` will appear in the correct position in the window, like this:

```xml
<Grid>
    <Canvas x:Name="MainBackLineCanvas" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
        <ItemsControl x:Name="MainBackLine" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        ...
        </ItemsControl>
    </<Canvas>
    <Canvas x:Name="MainColorLineCanvas" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
        <ItemsControl x:Name="MainColorLine" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        ...
        </ItemsControl>
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

The effect of this window is as follows:
[image]

The `MainBackLine`(the blue text) will be fully displayed at the beginning, the width of the `MainColorLine`(the yellow text) is set to 0 at the beginning, and the width will increase as the song time increases.

I used a `DispatcherTimer` to change its width. My code is as follows:

```cs
DispatcherTimer TextFlashTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
TextFlashTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 100);
TextFlashTimer.Tick += TextFlash;

private void TextFlash(object? sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //playTimePercent is the percentage of the playback progress of the current sentence, which is a Double variable
    MainColorLine.Width = ((playTimePercent > 0 && playTimePercent <1) ? playTimePercent : 1) * MainBackLine.ActualWidth;
}
```

When I run this code, the width of the `MainColorLine` will change very slowly and not smoothly. I've tried changing the `DispatcherTimer`'s `Interval`, or using `DoEvents`, but nothing works.

Is there any way to make it smoother please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use a DoubleAnimation to animate the width, e.g.:

```
double width = ((playTimePercent > 0 && playTimePercent < 1) ? playTimePercent : 1) * MainBackLine.ActualWidth;
DoubleAnimation doubleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation(width, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100)));
MainColorLine.BeginAnimation(FrameworkElement.WidthProperty, doubleAnimation);
```

Comment: Thank you! Now the display is very smooth. Should I use DoubleAnimation all the time I need to change the width and avoid changing the width property directly?